# extract data using sed or awk in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to merge data from 2 text files based on some condition.

I have two files:
1.txt

```
gera077||o||emi_riv_90@hotmail.com||||200.45.113.254||o||0f8caa3ced5dc172901a427410d20540
okan1993||||killa-o@hotmail.de||||84.141.125.140||o||69c1cb5ddbc66cceebe0dddba3eddf68
Tosiunia||||tosia_19@amorki.pl||o||83.22.193.86|||||ddcbba2076646980391cb4971b8030
DREP
glen-666||o||glen-666@hotmail.com||||84.196.42.167||o||f139d8b49085d012af9048bb1cba3534
Page 1
Sheyes1 ||||summer_faerie_dustyrose@yahoo.com|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
.
BenPhynix||||BenPhynix@aol.de||||| 62.226.181.57||||11dea24f1caebb012e11285579050f38
menopause |||totoche@wanadoo.fr||o||83.193.209.52||o||d7ca4d78fc79a795695ae1c161ce82ea
jonof.|o||joflem@medi3.no||o||213.161.242.106||o||239f33743e4a070b728d4dcbd1091f1a
```

2.txt

```
f139d8b49085d012af9048bb1cba3534: 12883 @: "#
d7ca4d78fc79a795695ae1c161ce82ea: 123422
0f8caa3ced5dc172901a427410d20540 :: demo
```

Contains the matching lines from 1.txt and hash is replaced with corresponding  value in 2.txt

result.txt

```
gera077 || o || emi_riv_90@hotmail.com || or || 200.45.113.254 || o ||: demo
glen-666-||glen-666@hotmail.com||||84.196.42.167||||12883 @: "#
menopause |||totoche@wanadoo.fr||o||83.193.209.52||o||123422
```

Contains the non-matching lines from 1.txt

left.txt

```
okan1993||||killa-o@hotmail.de||||84.141.125.140||o||69c1cb5ddbc66cceebe0dddba3eddf68
Tosiunia||||tosia_19@amorki.pl||o||83.22.193.86|||||ddcbba2076646980391cb4971b8030
DREP
Page 1
Sheyes1 ||||summer_faerie_dustyrose@yahoo.com|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
.
BenPhynix||||BenPhynix@aol.de||||| 62.226.181.57||||11dea24f1caebb012e11285579050f38
jonof.|o||joflem@medi3.no||o||213.161.242.106||o||239f33743e4a070b728d4dcbd1091f1a
```

The script I am trying is :

```
 awk -v s1="||o||" '
FNR==NR{
  a[$9]=$1 s1 $5;
  b[$9]=$13 s1 $17 s1 $21;
  c[$9]=$0;
  next
}
($1 in a){
  val=$1;
  $1="";
  sub(/:/,"");
  print a[val] s1 $0 s1 b[val];
  d[val]=$0;
  next
}
END{
for(i in d){
  delete c[i]
};
for(j in c){
  print c[j] > "left.txt"
}}
' FS="|" 1.txt FS=":" OFS=":" 2.txt > result.txt
```

But it is giving me **empty result.txt**

I am facing difficulty in debugging the issue.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Google-ing the first of the exposed email addresses brought a hit. You didn't publish real-life data as sample, did you? There are German addresses included. In Germany, privacy is a  broadly discussed topic... (probably much more than in other countries).

Comment: This is not a real data . So don't worry.

Comment: @downvoter, Please tell me the reason to downvote so that it can help me in the future.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I can see a couple of reasons why you would get downvoted: 1) You said `trying to merge data from 2 text files based on some condition` and then didn't tell us what that condition is, and 2) You said `Contains the matching lines` but didn't tell us in what way the lines "match" (e.g. based on some specific field numbers or something else). I'm very surprised anyone took the time to try to figure out what the relationship is between your input and output when you didn't take the time to just tell us.

Comment: @EdMorton , thanks for highlighting. I will keep these things in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following `awk`(completely based on your shown Input_file(s) and considering that your 2.txt will not have any duplicates on it too) and let me know if this helps you.

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$NF]=$0;next} $1~/:/{sub(/:/,"",$1);flag=1} ($1 in a){val=$1;if($0 ~ /:/ && !flag){sub(/[^:]*/,"");sub(/:/,"")};print a[val] OFS $0 > "result.txt";flag="";delete a[val]} END{for(i in a){print a[i]>"left.txt"}}' FS="|" 1.txt FS=" "  OFS="||o||" 2.txt
```

Output will be 2 files named `results.txt` and `left.txt`. Will add non-one liner form and explanation too for above code shortly.

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                                ##FNR and NR both are awk out of the box variables and they denote line numbers in Input_file(s), difference between them is FNR value will be RESET when it complete reading 1 Input_file and NR value will be keep increasing till it completes reading all the Input_file(s).
  a[$NF]=$0;                            ##Creating an array named a whose index is $NF(value of last field of current line) and value is current line.
  next                                  ##next is awk out of the box keyword which will skip all further statements now.
}
$1~/:/{                                 ##Checking condition here if current lines 1st field has a colon in it then do following:
  sub(/:/,"",$1);                       ##Using sub function of awk which will substitute colon with NULL of 1st field of current line of current Input_file.
  flag=1                                ##Setting a variable named flag here(basically to make sure that 1st colon is substituted so need for another colon removal.
}
($1 in a){                              ##Checking a condition here if current line $1 is present in array a then do following:
  val=$1;                               ##Setting variable named val value to $1 here.
  if($0 ~ /:/ && !flag){                ##Checking condition here if current line is having colon and variable flag is NOT NULL then do following:
     sub(/[^:]*/,"");                   ##Substituting all the values from starting to till colon comes with NULL.
     sub(/:/,"")};                      ##Then substituting only 1 colon here.
  print a[val] OFS $0 > "result.txt";   ##printing the value of array a whose index is variable val OFS(output field separator) current line values to output file named results.txt here.
  flag="";                              ##Unsetting the value of variable flag here.
  delete a[val]                         ##Deleting the value of array a whose index is variable val here.
}
END{                                    ##Starting end section of this awk program here. which will be executed once all Input_file(s) have been read.
  for(i in a){                          ##Traversing through the array a now.
     print a[i]>"left.txt"}             ##Printing the value of array a(which will basically provide those values which are NOT matched in both files) in left.txt file.
}
' FS="|" 1.txt FS=" " OFS="||o||" 2.txt ##Setting FS="|" for 1.txt Input_file and then setting FS=" " and OFS="||o||" for 2.txt Input_file, 1.txt and 2.txt are Input_files for this program to run.
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort and the help you have done so far. Is it possible to add some comments in the script so that I can learn from this answer ?

Comment: The output of result.txt is not correct. It is giving me 2 hash values instead of replacing it.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, as I had already mentioned in my comments in your post section, since your output delimiter is NOT consistent so I have kept it as space apart from that all values are looking correct, let me know on same.

Comment: I think the delimiter is ||o|| in result.txt

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla, add explanation too successfully now, enjoy learning, cheers :)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Appreciated

Comment: Nice explanation :-)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 But as far as I know, it is not possible to do `print a[val] OFS $0 > "result.txt"; ` Such redirections hadn't worked in the past. Are you sure, you could do it that way?

Comment: @sjsam, yes, it worked cool for me, I could see `||o||` in output file named results.txt. I believe that is print a,b will not work, a OFS b works as far as I tried in GNU `awk`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 My mistake. I was just going thru [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html) to see I was wrong :/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` script may also help.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\|";OFS="|"}NR==FNR{data[$1]=$2;}
     NR!=FNR{if($NF in data){
     $NF=data[$NF];print >"result.txt"
     }else{
     print >"left.txt"}
     }' <( sed 's/\s*:\s*/|/' 2.txt) 1.txt 2>/dev/null
```

**Output**

```
$ cat result.txt 
gera077||o||emi_riv_90@hotmail.com||||200.45.113.254||o||: demo
glen-666||o||glen-666@hotmail.com||||84.196.42.167||o||12883 @: "#
menopause |||totoche@wanadoo.fr||o||83.193.209.52||o||123422

$ cat left.txt 
okan1993||||killa-o@hotmail.de||||84.141.125.140||o||69c1cb5ddbc66cceebe0dddba3eddf68
Tosiunia||||tosia_19@amorki.pl||o||83.22.193.86|||||ddcbba2076646980391cb4971b8030
DREP
Page 1
Sheyes1 ||||summer_faerie_dustyrose@yahoo.com|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
.
BenPhynix||||BenPhynix@aol.de||||| 62.226.181.57||||11dea24f1caebb012e11285579050f38
jonof.|o||joflem@medi3.no||o||213.161.242.106||o||239f33743e4a070b728d4dcbd1091f1a
```

We have preprocessed the first file - using `sed` - to make its field delimiter `|` and used process substitution to pass the result to `awk`.